# SQL Query summing columns

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sum

Im new to sql currently using a book to learn it i have to tables

```
CREATE TABLE MOV (
    codigo NUMBER(5),
    tipo char(1),
    monto NUMBER(7, 2));

INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (1,'I',5000.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (2,'I',6000.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (3,'I',7000.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (4,'I',8000.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (5,'I',9000.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (6,'I',9500.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (7,'I',8500.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (8,'I',7500.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (9,'I',6500.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (10,'I',5500.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (1,'I',5650.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (2,'I',6650.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (3,'I',7650.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (4,'I',8650.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (5,'I',9650.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (6,'I',10150.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (7,'I',9150.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (8,'I',8150.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (9,'I',7150.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (10,'I',6150.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (1,'I',6300.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (2,'I',7300.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (3,'I',8300.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (4,'I',9300.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (5,'I',10300.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (6,'I',10800.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (7,'I',9800.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (8,'I',8800.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (9,'I',7800.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (10,'I',6800.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (1,'I',6950.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (2,'I',7950.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (3,'I',8950.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (4,'I',9950.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (5,'I',10950.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (6,'I',11450.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (7,'I',10450.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (8,'I',9450.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (9,'I',8450.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (10,'I',7450.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (1,'I',7600.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (2,'I',8600.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (3,'I',9600.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (4,'I',10600.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (5,'I',11600.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (6,'I',12100.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (7,'I',11100.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (8,'I',10100.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (9,'I',9100.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (10,'I',8100.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (1,'D',3800.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (2,'D',4300.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (3,'D',4800.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (4,'D',5300.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (5,'D',5800.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (6,'D',6050.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (7,'D',5550.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (8,'D',5050.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (9,'D',4550.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (10,'D',4050.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (1,'D',1900.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (2,'D',2150.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (3,'D',2400.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (4,'D',2650.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (5,'D',2900.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (6,'D',3025.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (7,'D',2775.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (8,'D',2525.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (9,'D',2275.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (10,'D',2025.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (1,'D',950.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (2,'D',1075.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (3,'D',1200.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (4,'D',1325.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (5,'D',1450.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (6,'D',1512.50);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (7,'D',1387.50);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (8,'D',1262.50);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (9,'D',1137.50);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (10,'D',1012.50);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (1,'I',2600.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (2,'I',2725.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (3,'I',2850.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (4,'I',2975.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (5,'I',3100.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (6,'I',3162.50);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (7,'I',3037.50);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (8,'I',2912.50);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (9,'I',2787.50);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (10,'I',2662.50);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (1,'D',650.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (2,'D',681.25);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (3,'D',712.50);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (4,'D',743.75);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (5,'D',775.00);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (6,'D',790.63);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (7,'D',759.38);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (8,'D',728.13);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (9,'D',696.88);
INSERT INTO MOV VALUES (10,'D',475.25);


CREATE TABLE EMPLE (
    codigo NUMBER(5),
    nombre char(40));

INSERT INTO EMPLE VALUES (1,'PEDRO PEREZ MORA');
INSERT INTO EMPLE VALUES (2,'MARIA BRENES ORTIZ');
INSERT INTO EMPLE VALUES (3,'CARLOS QUESADA BONILLA');
INSERT INTO EMPLE VALUES (4,'LUISA SOTO ABARCA');
INSERT INTO EMPLE VALUES (5,'OLMAN BADILLA CORTES');
INSERT INTO EMPLE VALUES (6,'ANA CAMACHO DIAZ');
INSERT INTO EMPLE VALUES (7,'ALVARO DUARTE ESPINOZA');
INSERT INTO EMPLE VALUES (8,'HAZEL ELIZONDO GAMBOA');
INSERT INTO EMPLE VALUES (9,'HUGO GARITA JIMENEZ');
INSERT INTO EMPLE VALUES (10,'LIDIETH JARA ECHANDI');
INSERT INTO EMPLE VALUES (11,'JOSE MORA QUIROS');
INSERT INTO EMPLE VALUES (12,'ROY PAZOS RODRIGUEZ');
```

the end result should be like this:

[image]

What I have is a simple select statement

```
select e.codigo, e.nombre
from mov e;
```

how can i make the query to have the result as intended in the image
thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: You appear to have no mechanism for uniquely identifying rows. So you're stuck I'm afraid.

Comment: @Strawberry is dead on. How are you going to identify those records? Your MOV table has no primary key so there is no way to identify, sum, and group by NOMBRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple LEFT JOIN with a GROUP BY should do it;

```
SELECT e.codigo, e.nombre, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN m.tipo = 'I' THEN m.monto ELSE 0 END) ingresos,
  SUM(CASE WHEN m.tipo = 'D' THEN m.monto ELSE 0 END) deducciones,
  SUM(CASE WHEN m.tipo = 'I' THEN m.monto ELSE 0 END) -
  SUM(CASE WHEN m.tipo = 'D' THEN m.monto ELSE 0 END) neto
FROM emple e
LEFT JOIN mov m
  ON e.codigo = m.codigo
GROUP BY e.codigo, e.nombre
ORDER BY e.codigo, e.nombre
```

The LEFT JOIN lets us collect up all corresponding "mov"s for each "emple", and the GROUP BY allows us to sum them up for each codigo/nombre combination.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1fb06f/4).

Answer (score 0):

You need to join these two tables if I understood.

Something like...

```
Select e.*,m.* from emple e,mov m where e.codigo = m.codigo;
```

Comment: @user3458416, you can't.